# How to change the canvas size in html2canvas plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

I need to download a payslip in pdf format, I am generate it in html format. Next I have plan to convert whole html to pdf, I found html2canvas js plugin and jsPDF plugin.
First I have convert the whole html to canvas and get the canvas DataURL add it to pdf and finally download but when I take print out it is not clear. So I debug the code and found the problem. The problem is when I convert the html to pdf using html2canvas plugin it return 1032x741 pixel(but A4 sheet needs 2480 x 3508), and when I put it into pdf it doesn't have clear.

I have used html2canvas and jsPDF plugin and tried the following code

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#lnkPDF").click(function() {
            html2canvas($("#all"), { //html div id
                onrendered: function(canvas) { //It returns 1032 x 741 pixel but require more
                    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/gif");
                    var doc = new jsPDF();
                    doc.setFontSize(40);
                    doc.text(35, 25, "Payslip");
                    doc.addImage(dataURL, 'bmp', i, 10, 200, 150);
                    doc.save('payslip.pdf');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried simply specifying the size in the HTML2Canvas options?  See [HERE](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html).

Comment: html2canvas($("#all"), {width: 2480,
                      height: 3508,
I tried but no use

Comment: One thing to remember is that html2canvas re-renders the page from the HTML/CSS - it's not a screen shot.  What size is the original content?

Comment: yes it is created using original content(1032 x 741), but how can I solve this problem. any solution.